# UPDATE desde un SELECT usando SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

En SQL Server, es posible hacer un `INSERT INTO` a una tabla usando un `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (col, col2, col3)
    SELECT col, col2, col3 FROM otra_tabla WHERE sql = 'ok'
```

¿Es esto tambien posible para un `UPDATE`? Tengo una tabla temporal que contiene los valores, y me gustaria actualizar otra tabla usando esos valores. Tal vez algo asi como:

```
UPDATE tabla SET col1, col2
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM otra_tabla WHERE sql = 'ok'
    WHERE tabla.id = otra_tabla.id
```

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Traducción literal de [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334741)

Se puede hacer de la siguiente manera. Fíjate que la consulta iguala las dos tablas por el campo clave que las dos tengan en común.

```
UPDATE
    Tabla_A
SET
    Tabla_A.col1 = Tabla_B.col1,
    Tabla_A.col2 = Tabla_B.col2
FROM
    alguna_tabla AS Tabla_A
    INNER JOIN otra_tabla AS Tabla_B
        ON Tabla_A.id = Tabla_B.id
WHERE
    Tabla_A.col3 = 'ok'
```

En el caso en que la tabla destino no tenga esos campos vacíos, y pueda haber datos que ya existan desde el origen, conviene utilizar una consulta que verifique antes de hacer el `UPDATE`, ya que un proceso de `UPDATE` hace primero un `DELETE` y luego un `INSERT`

Se podria hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE
     Tabla
SET
     Tabla.col1 = otra_tabla.col1,
     Tabla.col2 = otra_tabla.col2 
FROM
     Tabla
INNER JOIN     
     otra_tabla
ON     
     Tabla.id = otra_tabla.id 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT Tabla.Col1, Tabla.Col2 EXCEPT SELECT otra_tabla.Col1, otra_tabla.Col2))
```

Comment: Tomar en cuenta que de esta forma estarás actualizando todos los valores que cruzan entre las tablas, independiente de si los valores son los mismos o no. Vale decir, podrías estar haciendo trabajo extra

Comment: @Lamak está traduciendo para [Las preguntas con enlaces cruzados](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1321/127)... Creo que por el tipo de pregunta/respuesta, es el resultado típico de una búsqueda en Google de "*SQL Server SELECT UPDATE*"... Sería genial agregarle más info para subirle un poco la calidad.