# Seleccionar dos campos y usarlos para un update dentro de la misma tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una tabla en SQL Server llamada prods, tengo dos campos que quiero consultar y unir para hacer el update a un campo de la misma tabla, lo hago con la siguiente sentencia

```
select url, articulo
from prods 
where articulo = 's-111'
```

por lo que me regresa las cadenas **c:\imagenes\productos, s-111**, esos son los datos que quiero unir en el campo imagen, utilizo el siguiente update en la misma sentencia

```
update prods set imagen =  '" + url& " " & articulo + "' 
where articulo = 's-111'
```

pero me graba el siguiente resultado

**" + url & " " & articulo + "**

el resultado esperado seria

**c:\imagenes\productos\s-111**

Estoy metiendo el where por que solo estaba probando con un articulo, pero quiero hacerlo con todos los articulos de mi tabla prods, es decir la suma de esos dos campos de cada uno de sus registros

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48596/update-desde-un-select-usando-sql-server) también hay una respuesta que te podría servir.

Comment: Hola Erick, podrias marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te haya resultado mas util, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo quieres hacer un `UPDATE` a partir de los resultados de un `SELECT`.

Sin dar muchas vueltas lo puedes lograr a través de la instrucción `SQL MERGE`, la cual se describe [en la documentación oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) así:

> SQL MERGE Ejecuta operaciones de inserción, actualización o eliminación en una tabla de destino a partir de los resultados de una combinación con una tabla de origen.

Con esto en mente, puedes utilizar la misma tabla como origen y destino. Lo ideal es que tengas un campo único que identifique a cada registro, como por ejemplo un `OID` auto incrementable.

```
MERGE prods AS DESTINO 
USING(SELECT CONCAT(url, '\', articulo) AS RUTA FROM prods) AS ORIGEN
ON ORIGEN.oid = DESTINO.oid
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET imagen = ORIGEN.RUTA;
```

Con esto estarías actualizando el campo **imagen** de la tabla **prods** con el resultado de concatenar la **url**, el caracter \ y el **articulo**, justo como lo quieres hacer:

*c:\imagenes\productos\s-111*

Si no tienes un `OID` único, se puede complicar un poco la ejecución.

**Siempre es recomendable hacer una copia de la información antes de experimentar o hacer estos ejercicio en ambientes de pruebas para evitar pérdida de información.**

Comment: A esta respuesta sólo le añadiría la explicación de lo que falla en la lógica del OP. Está dándole una cadena (entre comillas simples) y supone que sql server va a leer la cadena y procesarla. El punto es precísamente no darle una cadena sino una operación entre columnas de un select. O complicarlo un poco más y poner eso en variables, concatenar, blabla.

Comment: Es cierto que la pregunta del op está un poco rara de desentrañar, yo entendí lo más obvio y eso fue lo que le respondí, interesante tu respuesta, pero mi opinión es que el quiere simplemente concatenar y primero explica con el select, no creo que quiera usar un update partiendo de un select, no se si me hago entender

Answer (score 0):

```
update prods
set image = concat(URL, '\\', artículo);
```

Usas la **función concat** para unir los campos deseados y pones **'\'** ya que la **barra invertida** es un caracter especial, esto recibe el nombre de **"escapar un caracter"**.